# How to FIX OutOfMemoryError for seemingly very light resource 64 byte

Tags: android, android-layout, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, android-imageview

I have got a android.view.InflateException, and further down the stacktrace, I've got this outOfMemory exception at the line where a 4 kb XML drawable is loaded with srcCombat into an AppCompatImageView.

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_profile_arrow" />
```

StackTrace::

```
Caused by java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 64 byte allocation with 3187176 free bytes and 3112KB until OOM, target footprint 402653184, growth limit 402653184; giving up on allocation because <1% of heap free after GC.
   at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflateChildElements(VectorDrawable.java:853)
   at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.inflate(VectorDrawable.java:752)
```

Whats the meaning of this, I mean, if there is  3187176 free bytes why can't a 64 byte be allocated?

Whats the meaning of OOM, target footprint, and growth limit.

Comment: Don’t focus on the “64 byte allocation” in the message. Instead focus on the “*giving up on allocation because <1% of heap free after GC*” part. According to the message, the environment is configured with ~400MB heap size, but there are only ~3MB left even after the GC tried to free unused space. This means either, the configured heap space is too small or you have a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks, Holger for looking into this,
Configured help space is too small - what does this mean? We can't control the mobile environment, right?
Whats the best tool for resolving memory leaks.

Comment: I mean, 'configured heap space'

Comment: the question “how to analyze memory leaks in java” is too broad, but entering it into the search engine of your choice will provide you plenty of starting points. “What is the best tool for this” is an open question and asking for opinions. I suggest to start on your own and come back to SO when you can narrow down the question, e.g. to a specific problem with a specific tool or when you have identified a (potential problematic) part of your code that needs to be fixed.